# How to find href to match with the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select the `<a>` that its ending href matches with the userID and adminID that are both arrays extracted from the URL? I am trying the following, but it is not working.

```
if (userID == adminID){
    $("a[href$=userID]").css('color','blue');                           
}
```

Comment: Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead: `\`a[href$=${userID}]\``

Comment: Try `$(\`a[href$=${userID}]\`).css('color','blue');`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I thought the same... how did you get the backticks to show correctly in the comment code format? backtick-example-backtick

Comment: I used a "\" to escape them

Comment: Or string concatenation if you need browser support that doesn't allow template literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User id is missing from the selector and needs to have wrapping parenthesis around the value. Working example below:

```js
// Anchor elements implement Location object, makes for a good mock
const mockLocation = document.createElement('a');
mockLocation.href = 'http://www.foobar.com/admin/123/user/123/';

const pathnameParts = mockLocation.pathname.split('/');

const adminId = pathnameParts[2];
const userId = pathnameParts[4];

if (adminId === userId){
  $(`a[href="/user/${userId}"]`).css('color','purple');             
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/user/123">User 123</a>
<a href="/user/129">User 129</a>
```